# View and edit land parcels in MapWinGIS

Tags: vb.net, mapwingis

I am developing a GIS_desktop application with VB.NET and MapWinGIS.  When I load a shapefile into the application, it is displaying blocks instead of the actual polygons

[image: display shapefile].

The shapefile is supposed to display the polygons as shown in the attached

[image: original shapefile]

Comment: Are you sure you just haven't forgot to set a border somewhere? That's how it would look if it used the same color as the fill.

Comment: Thank you for your response l managed to solve the problem using another method. l went back to my code and set the line width to 2.

Comment: Please write up a short answer with the solution and accept it.

Comment: using this code
'Dim linewidth As Single
Dim inHandle As integer
linewidth =2
AxMpap1.set_ShapeLineWidth(intHandle,lineWidth)'

Comment: An answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to add line width, shape fill color and line color

```
enter code here
Public Sub LayerSymbology()         
    Dim LineWidth As Single           
    Dim FillColor As UInt32           
    Dim FIllLine As UInt32

    FillColor = Convert.ToInt32(RGB(100, 255, 0))            
    FillLine = Convert.ToInt32(RGB(0, 0, 0))            
    LineWidth = 2

    AxMap1.set_ShapeLayerFillColor(intHandle, FillColor)            
    AxMap1.set_ShapeLayerLineColor(intHandle, FIllLine)            
    AxMap1.set_ShapeLayerLineWidth(intHandle, LineWidth)
End Sub 

Private Sub ToolsStripButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles BtnFile.Click             
    Dim shpfile As New MapWinGIS.Shapefile            
    Dim openDig As New OpenFileDialog

    openDig.Filter = "Supported Formats|*.shp*"  
    openDig.CheckFileExists = True

    If openDig.ShowDialog(Me) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then       
        shpfile.Open(openDig.FileName)         
        AxMap1.AddLayer(shpfile, True)
    End If

    LayerSymbology()
End Sub
```